# Forge Viewer: VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT raise all the time

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im using `VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT` to catch when viewer resize but it raise all the time even it doesnt has any change (take a look attached pic). And when i use that method, objects do not highlight when mouse move over anymore. I solved the problem by different way is catch resize div event, it works perfectly. So`VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT` really has a problem or i misunderstand how to use it?
Appreciated any comments.

[image: resize event problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT` definitely shouldn't be called all the time. Such a behavior is usually a sign of some problematic JavaScript code where, for example, some piece of code reacts to this event and (accidentally or intentionally) causes some change in the viewer size, causing an infinite loop of resize events.

When you try any of the official sample apps, you'll see that the event is really only triggered when the viewer canvas size actually changes.